# Online portfolios for college music professors?

Tags: job-search

I am returning to the academic world to pursue my teaching career.

I have been a professional musician for over 50 years, and I want to have an online portfolio using software that is generally accepted by academic decision makers.

The portfolio will include movies, MP3 files, links, professional recommendations, my artistic statement, and my teaching philosophy.

I’m curious to find out if anyone knows if there is a generally accepted format, blog, website, and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**
I am a Computer Science professor, so not an authority on this question, but my institution encourages personal websites last I checked.

**Background**
Several years ago when I was researching new [Learning Management Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_management_system) (LMS), I interviewed various department chairs around campus to determine what their department needs would look like if we moved to a new LMS. The department chairs for Music and Performing Arts brought up concerns similar to this question. Their responses were the same:

- LMS systems do not offer anything meaningful for student or faculty portfolios.
- There is some software available for hosting online portfolios but it was costly; I do not remember specific software names anymore.
- Personal websites were the *easiest* and relatively cost effective option:

  - Easiest being a relative term here since traditionally many music and art students/faculty have had limited tech skills to build and manage their own website.

It has been a few years since I had these conversations and there are plenty of free or relatively affordable drag-and-drop style website builders now. I am also noticing that our student body as a whole is fairly tech savvy and personal websites have become our standard for portfolios.

Dance students will often use a website or blog to share videos and playlists from YouTube. This allows visitors to their site to continue watching their performances on YouTube in a curated playlist. You can also [unlist](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177) videos so only people who clicked through your website or blog can see them and they are not publicly available on YouTube.